# Copulas and theta roles

Tags: syntax, minimalism

Hi I was wondering if and if so which theta roles are being discharged to the DPs/NPs in sentences such as "these are French men". Also I was asking myself what kind of structure one would give to these VPs and their arguments (?).

Comment: This is fun. Indeed, I haven't often come across syntactic discussions of identificational copulas/sentences. Seems likely that we need some sort of a dedicated *be*-of-identification (sorry, not sure what happened to<sub>subscripts</sub>) that takes two `symmetrical' things. Themes?

Comment: Also, welcome to Linguistics SE :) And also, this question would certainly benefit if you edit it and throw in whatever your own hypotheses are.

Comment: My impression is that your sentence is, in all respects relevant to theta roles, exactly like this one: _He is a good player._  And the latter case is discussed at length e.g. in the paper ['The phrase structure of the copula'](http://lohndal.com/wp-content/uploads/copula06.pdf), where you can find additional references.